# won't complete the do while loop

Tags: java, loops, runtime-error, do-while

EDIT: I have some corrections as an answer. I needed to use another do-while loop for different scenarios in the slot machine. I have figured out the answer to this particular question and have posted the answer for anyone who would like to use this for help.

I have a single do while loop that will not finish. In order to enter the do while loop, I need to enter a number. It will not start unless the user enters something- it will give a mismatch error if one enters a letter which is understandable, but **how can I get into the loop without the user entering anything?**

Also, would putting in another do loop solve the problem of it not fully running? I'm confused as to the logic of it and my pseudocode is wrong. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class Slot2
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int number;

    System.out.println ("Welcome to the Slot Machine Simulator!");
    System.out.println ("\nActions\n1. Start a new game\n2. Scores\n3. Exit");
    System.out.print ("\nPlease select an action: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 3)
    {
    System.out.print ("\nThat is not an option. Please select an item number between 1-3: ");
    option = keyboard.nextInt();
    break;
    }

    if (option == 1)
    {
        String username; 
        double startingTotal = 100.0;
        double userTotal = startingTotal;

        System.out.print ("\nBefore the game begins, please enter your name: ");
        username = keyboard.next( );
        System.out.print ("\nGame start! You will begin with $100.00. Enter a negative value to quit the game. Good luck, " + username + "!");

        do **//you have to enter a number here to get the 1st print statement,this is the error**
        {
            double bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
            bet = 0.0;
            userTotal = startingTotal - bet;

            System.out.print ("You currently have: $%.2f" + startingTotal + "\nHow much would you like to bet?"); **//this is the part of the loop that works**

            double winnings = 0.0;
            double userFinalTotal = 0.0;

            Random generator = new Random();
            int slot1 = generator.nextInt(6);

            int slot2 = generator.nextInt(6);

            int slot3 = generator.nextInt(6);

            String firstSlot = "";

            switch (slot1)
            {
                case 0:
                    firstSlot = "Cherries";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    firstSlot = "Oranges";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    firstSlot = "Plums";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    firstSlot = "Bells";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    firstSlot = "Melons";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    firstSlot = "Bars";
                    break;
            }

            String secondSlot = "";

            switch (slot2)
            {
                case 0:
                    secondSlot = "Cherries";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    secondSlot = "Oranges";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    secondSlot = "Plums";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    secondSlot = "Bells";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    secondSlot = "Melons";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    secondSlot = "Bars";
                    break;
            }

            String thirdSlot = "";

            switch (slot3)
            {
                case 0:
                    thirdSlot = "Cherries";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    thirdSlot = "Oranges";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    thirdSlot = "Plums";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    thirdSlot = "Bells";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    thirdSlot = "Melons";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    thirdSlot = "Bars";
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println ("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println ("" + firstSlot + "    " + secondSlot + "    " + thirdSlot);
            System.out.print ("-------------------------------");

            if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3)
            {
                winnings = bet * 3;
                userFinalTotal = userTotal + winnings;
                System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 3. You win: $%.2f", winnings); 
                System.out.printf ("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", userFinalTotal);
            }
            else if ((slot1 == slot2 && slot2 != slot3) || (slot1 == slot3 && slot1 != slot2) || (slot2 == slot3 && slot3 != slot1))
            {   
                winnings = bet * 2;
                userFinalTotal = userTotal + winnings;
                System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 2. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                System.out.printf ("\nYou currently have: $%.2fn", userFinalTotal);
            }   
            else
            {
                System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 0. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                System.out.printf ("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", userFinalTotal);
            }       

        if ((bet < 0) || (userFinalTotal <= 0))
        {
            break;
        }

        while (bet > userFinalTotal)
        {
            System.out.print("\nYour bet is greater than your current total. Please enter a valid amount: ");
            bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        } while (userTotal > 0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to be clearer about what your asking, because your question does not seem to make much sense. Aside from the inappropriate `break` in your first loop (which while loop are you referring to, by the way?) the user input part seems to correctly do what you describe, at a glance. I cannot put "I have a loop that does not finish" and "How do I get into the loop without the user entering anything?" (among other things) together into one coherent question.

Comment: @Jason C  I thought by stating I had a problem with a do while loop and then commenting on the exact do while loop where the error occurred I was being clear, but sorry for the confusion. I will fix the inappropriate break statement in the initial while loop; however, my real issue as stated in the question is with the do while loop. It only runs part of the way through to the marked comment (only prints the first statement, also marked).

Comment: @JasonC To expound on your question regarding entering the number, the program will run until it gets to the do-while. Then, if I enter a number (say 1) it will run until only the first print statement in the loop (also marked with a comment). If you could explain the logic in an error such as this I would really appreciate it- I don't want to make a mistake like this again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `username = keyboard.next( );` to `username = keyboard.nextLine( );`, I am sure it will work.

There is nothing wrong with your `do-while` loop.

---

On top of that, you shouldn't declare these variables inside your while loop.

```
String username; 
double startingTotal = 100.0;
double userTotal = startingTotal;
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I think that may have solved the do-while problem, I just have to fix the other errors that came from it!

Answer (score 0):

I have a printwriter statement in a do-while loop in order to print the scores of every user that plays the slot machine. However, I think because of this scores print multiple times when it says to view scores (option 2). Is this because of the variable used, or the fact it is in a do-while loop?
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.io.*;

```
public class Slot3
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println ("Welcome to the Slot Machine Simulator!");

    int option = 0;

    //if the user selects a 1 or 2 (does not want to exit) then this loop will run
    do
    {
        System.out.println ("\nActions\n1. Start a new game\n2. Scores\n3. Exit");
        System.out.print ("\nPlease select an action: ");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        option = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        while (option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 3)
        {
            System.out.print ("\nThat is not an option. Please select an item number between 1-3: ");
            option = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        //this will occur if the user selects 1 to play the game
        if (option == 1)
        {
            double money = 100.00;
            double bet = 0.00;
            double winnings = 0.00;
            double score = 0.00;
            int count = 0;

            System.out.print ("\nBefore the game begins, please enter your name: ");
            String username = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print ("\nGame start! You will begin with $100.00. Enter a negative value to quit the game. Good luck, " + username + "!");

            System.out.printf("\nYou currently have $%.2f.", 100.00);

            do 
            {
                System.out.printf("\n\nHow much would you like to bet? ");
                bet = keyboard.nextDouble();

                if ((bet < 0) || (money <= 0))
                {
                    break;
                }

                while (bet > money)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYour bet is greater than your current total. Please enter a valid amount: ");
                    bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
                }

                //create random numbers
                Random generator = new Random();
                int slot1 = generator.nextInt(6);

                int slot2 = generator.nextInt(6);

                int slot3 = generator.nextInt(6);

                String firstSlot = "";

                switch (slot1)
                {
                    case 0:
                        firstSlot = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        firstSlot = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        firstSlot = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        firstSlot = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        firstSlot = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        firstSlot = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                String secondSlot = "";

                switch (slot2)
                {
                    case 0:
                        secondSlot = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        secondSlot = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        secondSlot = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        secondSlot = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        secondSlot = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        secondSlot = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                String thirdSlot = "";

                switch (slot3)
                {
                    case 0:
                        thirdSlot = "Cherries";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        thirdSlot = "Oranges";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        thirdSlot = "Plums";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        thirdSlot = "Bells";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        thirdSlot = "Melons";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        thirdSlot = "Bars";
                        break;
                }

                System.out.println ("\n-------------------------------");
                System.out.printf ("%-12s%-10s%5s\n", firstSlot , secondSlot , thirdSlot);
                System.out.print ("\n-------------------------------");

                //check how many of the slots match to calculate the winnings
                if (slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3)
                {
                    winnings = bet * 3;
                    money -= bet;
                    score = money + winnings;
                    System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 3. You win: $%.2f", winnings); 
                     System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", score);
                }
                else if ((slot1 == slot2 && slot2 != slot3) || (slot1 == slot3 && slot1 != slot2) || (slot2 == slot3 && slot3 != slot1))
                {   
                    winnings = bet * 2;
                    money -= bet;
                    score = money + winnings;
                    System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 2. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", score);
                }   
                else
                {
                    winnings = bet * 0;
                    money -= bet;
                    score = money + winnings;
                    System.out.printf ("\nNumber of matches: 0. You win: $%.2f", winnings);
                    System.out.printf("\nYou currently have: $%.2f", score);
                }     
            } while ((bet > 0) && (money > 0)); 

            FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("scores.txt", true);
            PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
            outputWriter.printf("\n\n%1s%15s" , "Name" , "Score");
            outputWriter.printf ("\n\n%1s%15s" , "----" , "-----");
            outputWriter.printf ("\n\n%1s%15s" , username , score);
            outputWriter.close();

            System.out.println("\n\nGame over! Your score has been written to scores.txt, " + username + "!");

        } //end of actions for select option 1

        //option 2 user wants to read their scores
        if (option == 2)
        {
            File myFile = new File("scores.txt");

            //if there are no scores to read
            if (!myFile.exists())
            {   
                System.out.println("There are no scores to display at this time.");
                continue;
            }

            File file = new File("scores.txt");

            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                String username = inputFile.nextLine(); 

                System.out.println(username);
            }
            inputFile.close();
        } //close option 2
    } while (option != 3); //close 1st do-while loop

    if (option == 3)
    {
        System.out.print ("\nGoodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
Int counter = 0, input = 0;
While(counter < 10 && input = 0)
{
Thread.sleep(1000);
Counter++;
input = Scan.nextInt()
}
```

Not the greatest code I did this from my phone so

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering this. Can you explain your answer? Where would this go and why would I use it to fix it? I am new to Java and I just looked up Thread.sleep and it is used to to suspend execution for a short period of time? Sorry I have not gone over this before. @JGerulskis